# Do you find somebody something?

Tags: meaning, word-order

You do 'find something for somebody', but is 'find somebody something' equally correct English?

Comment: More context, please. Do you mean as in **I find you attractive**, or **I'll find you something to eat**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is correct English. You can say for example:

"Can you find me my bag?"

OR

"Can you find my bag for me?"

Comment: True so far as it goes, but I don't think many of us would say *I'll find something to eat for you*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Isn't this a different construction? It's verb-noun-to infinitive. The case in the question is verb-noun person-noun object.

Comment: I don't think so. To me, "something to eat" is primarily just a noun phrase - which grammatically is no different to "some supper", for example. I think it's largely a matter of *how long that noun phrase is*. How about switching to the "for" construction in *I'll find you something tasty* as opposed to *I'll find you something that will tickle your palate*? For my money, you can do it with the first, but with the second it seems a bit "iffy".